# How to have the functionality of FileField's "upload_to" parameter without actually uploading anything?

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    audio = models.FileField()
```

that I instantiate in the view like this:

```
sample = Sample()
sample.audio = 'audio/sample.mp4'
```

However, I would like to avoid having to provide the `audio/` part of the filepath in the view whenever I create an object of this class, and have it defined in the model instead.

I could add `upload_to` parameter like this:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
        audio = models.FileField(upload_to='audio')
```

but it will only work when something is actually uploaded, which is not my case. My files will already sit in the `MEDIA_ROOT/audio` folder.

How can I avoid providing such full path for a media file whenever I create an object from model?

Comment: You want to write just strings in FileField ?

Comment: Yes, just a path that will be appended to `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Comment: `sample = Sample.objects.get(pk=1)`
`sample.audio.path = 'my/path/something.png'`
`sample.save()`

Comment: Have you tried it?  [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) say that `upload_to` should work for `FileSystemStorage`: "... the string value will be appended to your MEDIA_ROOT path ..."

Comment: @RishiG: Yes, I have. I have also read the passage from the docs you cite and understood it the same. It won't work unless I add the `audio/` prefix as in my example. Possibly it would work if I performed "actual" upload, but I don't know what this might mean.

Comment: Just a question, do you intend to save your `Sample` object to the database? Do you intend then to be able to fetch a `sample` and use the file `sample.audio` as a proper `File` object? Then you can't use a string there. You need to assign a file object (python `file` or django `File`). When saving the `sample`, it'll automatically save the file to `upload_to` (so it'll copy the file). If you don't want this behaviour, don't use a `FileField`, but create your own field, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300033/avoid-copying-when-adding-a-large-file-to-filefield).

Comment: @dirkgroten: Thanks for suggestions. Yes, I actually do save `Sample` objects to database. In `FileField` I provide only the name of the file that sits in `MEDIA_ROOT` that I want to move to `upload_to` location upon `save()`. However, this is not what happens. The object will be saved to database, but will still refer to the file in `MEDIA_ROOT` location and also won't be moved to `upload_to` location.

Comment: correct, you can provide just the name of the file, but then it doesn't use `upload_to`. It only uses `upload_to` if you use a file object (rather than the file path). So if you use the file path, you have to pass the entire file path relative to MEDIA_ROOT, there's no way around it.

Comment: if you want to move the file to the `upload_to` folder, open the file (`with open('my_file.jpg', rb) as my_file:`) and assign that file object to `sample.audio`. Then when you save, it'll copy the file to the `upload_to` folder.